# securely restoring iPhone from backup

Tags: iphone, backup

Let's say you have an iPhone. Someone else gets physical control of the phone, successfully logs in, installs a backdoor that lives inside any local restore functionality (e.g. if you used the phone's native restore to factory settings features, it'll restore the backdoor as well), then returns the phone to you.

1. When you bought the phone, you obtained a full backup of the phone, OS, drivers, boot loader, bios, etc, that you trust (it's sitting on top of a rainbow protected by your pet unicorn). How did you create that backup?
2. How did you confirm that backup contains *everything*?
3. How do you restore from that trusted backup, guaranteeing everything on the phone prior to the restore operation was erased or overwritten?
4. How do you test that this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

This question, to be honest, is wholly unanswerable and entirely theoretical.

1. On an iPhone, or really any other Android device AFAIK, you cannot backup and restore the entire chain. You can snapshot the system images and restore those but once you start trying to capture above that you'll have fewer and fewer devices until it's just not something that you can do without attaching probes to the chips and dumping them. Only governments really do this, and even then it's very very expensive especially on modern devices which are so small.
2. Unless you have something to compare it against you simply cannot know that a) you got it all and b) you got it all *correctly*. The only reason Apple can verify the flash as part of their restore process is that they know what it should be and have hashes. This isn't so much a security issue as a fundamental truth about reality.
3. This one, actually, may be doable if you have enough cash. Assuming a godlike attacker hasn't figured out how to infect read only chips, you can wire up directly to the chip and flash the dump you took previously. But wait! What if the memory chip has been infected! The basic firmware for these devices is almost universally read only and so the previous condition applies. If you can trust that the chip is doing what you tell it, you can erase it fully and reflash your image.
4. See #2 mostly but if you can trust the manufacturer's firmware not to lie to you, you can manually pull data off to verify.

As a theoretical exercise, this question is a fun one. The thing is, we have to trust many things in our life to be doing what we think/are told they are doing. How do you know you're not slowly being poisoned through your food anytime you eat out? You can't conceivably test all your food because if you did you wouldn't have anything to eat! You'll just have to trust.

Answer (score -1):

Only answering 4. since this is a precondition to the other questions: Correct me if I am wrong, but the security model of Apple expects you to fully trust them or otherwise you cannot be sure. Only the hardware and the bootloader checking for signatures, secure boot etc will be able to guarantee this. So for the ordinary user there is no place to check the low-level stuff for tampered content.